# Проблема с библиотекой Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Есть картинка

```
<a href="/images/portfolio/0fd3eab5a4fcc4fbc47f8201242e5fc8.jpg" class="gallery" data-lightbox="example-1">
                    <img src="/images/portfolio/735f528f31af2d71e84a622e489c416b.jpg" alt="Пример Сайта визитки" class="example-image">
                </a>
```

По высоте очень большая. Устанавливаю значения Fancybox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.gallery").fancybox(
            {                       
"padding" : 20,
          "imageScale" : false, 

            "frameWidth" : 700,  
            "frameHeight" : 600, 
            "overlayShow" : true, 
            "overlayOpacity" : 0.8, 
            "hideOnContentClick" :false,
            "centerOnScroll" : false    
            });
});
</script>
```

По ширине не влазеет в экран.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ставлю "imageScale" : true, то слишком мелко

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема? Рабочий пример [тут](http://md.com.kz/)